# Issue working with Doubly-linked Lists in C

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

to start with
I am trying to read the list from a file and then writing it in another file and display it at the output. The problem is that I think that the reading function works, but when I try to call the displayData function, I keep getting an infinite loop. I am a beginner at this chapter, so I can't figure it out why does this keep happening. Here is my 2 functions:

```
void readData() {
    FILE* f;
    f=fopen("data.in","r");
    first = last = NULL;
    while (!feof(f)) {
        p = (NodeT *)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
        fscanf(f,"%d",&p->key);
        if (first == NULL) { /* empty list */
            first = last = p;
            p->next = p->prev = NULL;
        }
        else { /*nonempty list */
            last->next = p;
            p->prev = last;
            last = p;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}

void displayData() {
    FILE* f;
    f=fopen("data.out","w");
    for (p = first; p!= NULL; p = p->next) {
        printf("%d ",p->key);
        fprintf(f,"%d ",p->key);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Also, to be noted, my data.in is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.
Also my struct thingie:

```
typedef struct node_type {
    int key;
    struct node_type *next, *prev;
}NodeT;

NodeT *p, *first, *last;
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Usual LL question - no debugging done.  DCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    else { /*nonempty list */
        last->next = p;
        p->prev = last;
        last = p;
    }
```

You're not initializing `p->next` in the non-empty list case.  It should be NULL, because there's no next element when you're pushing to the end.

```
    else { /*nonempty list */
        last->next = p;
        p->prev = last;
        p->next = NULL;
        last = p;
    }
```